# How to visualize the limit of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{$x$ rational} \\
-x, & \text{$x$ irrational}
\end{cases}
$$

$
\text{This function is not continuous at any point except 0.}
$

Intuitively, I am able to understand but mathematically, I am not able to argue, how this statement is true.

$\lim_{x\to0-}$ or $\lim_{x\to0+}$ seems to have infinite fluctuations between x and -x.

```
What should be the proper argument to prove this statement?
```

Comment: Hint: $|f(x)|=|x|$.

Comment: I don't know if this is proper. But there are proofs that show, between every two rational numbers there is an irrational number. Also between every two irrational numbers there is a rational. In a way since there is no such thing as two real numbers "next to" each other, I believe this is where the problem is that you get the infinite fluctuations. But this is not a rigorous explanation. Perhaps someone else has a better one.

Comment: @MathHype That's exactly why I am not able to visualize how limit exists at 0.

Comment: I believe the hint above is what you want. The partitioned function is very similar to that of the absolute value function, and by taking the absoluted value of both sides, you can see that any sequence you take as a limit at zero will go to zero. While the numbers may be flip flopping from positive to negative, the distance from zero will always converge to zero. I give credit to @sranthrop

Answer (score 1):

Formally, let $\varepsilon > 0$, and define $\delta=\varepsilon$. Assume $|x-0|=|x|<\delta$. Then $|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=|x|<\delta=\varepsilon$. We have proven that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.

The fact that sign changes happen infinitely many times in any neighborhood of zero doesn't turn out to be a problem, because when $x$ is arbitrarily small, $x$ is arbitrarily close to $-x$. Perhaps a more visually intuitive example of this phenomenon would be $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$. Both of these functions are in the "cone" between $y=x$ and $y=-x$ and bounce back and forth between them infinitely many times near zero. Yet because both $y=x$ and $y=-x$ are going to zero, these functions get "squeezed" to have limit zero.